# Change width and height using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a simple task, changing the width and height of a div id using javascript. This is my code and I just can't get it to work. Is there something I'm forgetting to add?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box">
    Hello!
</div>

<script src="main.js"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeSize() {
document.getElementById('box').setAttribute("style","display:block;width:300px;background-color:blue;");
document.getElementById('box').style.width='300px';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue in refering your script, it does not have a `>` tag

```
<script src="main.js"> </script>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/bo6r4b9L/4/)**

Comment: thanks for the response! I actually do have that in my original code, just missed it here. Sorry! Do you have any other possible ideas as to why it isn't running properly?

Comment: @Marie check the demo

Comment: mar as answer if it had helped

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling the function itself...

You need to call it after load the script or convert it to anonymous function here is the [demo](https://jsbin.com/ziruhak/edit?html,output)